# "the item you were attempting to purchase could not be found"

Tags: android

I google it again and again but there is no useful information for me.

here is the situation:
1. the products are active.
2. I tested my apk by testing account.
3. I have uploaded the apk for a whole day.

but when I want to pay for the items in the app,googleplay appear that message.And I have checked for hour and hour,but still find nothing useful.

is there anyone who faced this problem and solved it ?
thanks!

Comment: and the package name in apk is the same with googleplay's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried everything on the checklist here? http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test

Comment: I solved it,the signature uploaded before is diffrent with the new one.so I uploaded the old signature and no problems any more.